# How to make columns the same width and fill the entire space in width and height?

Tags: html

I create a page with a table that should fill the entire browser window in width and height. The first row is the heading, the second row contains three cells: the width of the first cell should be according to its content (fixed), the widths of the second and third should be equal and occupy all the remaining space in width and height. The problem is that when I set their widths through the `<col width="50%">` tag, they are rendered different in widths!

Here is a minimal working example reproducing the issue:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: #CCCCCC;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        table {
            border-spacing: 15px 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .panelsMain {
            display: inline-block;
            background: white;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 98%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="mainTable">
        <col width="auto">
        <col width="50%">
        <col width="50%">
        <tr height="50px" valign="top">
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <p style="width:200px">
                    some objects of fixed width
                </p>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" height="100%">
                <div class="panelsMain">
                    sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
                </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" height="100%">
                <div class="panelsMain">
                    fffffffff
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

What can I do in order to make the second and third columns equail in width?

---

### **UPDATE**

With the approach suggested by [Aravind Anil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6512929/aravind-anil) I came to the following solution which almost perfectly fits my needs, excepting wrong distance between the panels (which should be equal to `15px` as `border-spacing:` in `table`):

```html
<html>    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: #CCCCCC;
            margin: 0px;
        }    
        table {
            border-spacing: 15px 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }    
        .panelsMain {
            display: inline-block;
            background: white;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: 50%;
            height: 98%;
        }
    </style>
</head>    
<body>
<table id="mainTable">
    <col width="auto">
    <col width="auto">
    <tr height="50px" valign="top">
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td valign="top">
         <p style="width:200px">some objects of fixed width</p>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" height="100%"><nobr>
          <div class="panelsMain">sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</div>
          <div class="panelsMain">fffffffff</div></nobr>
       </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body></html>
```

An attempt to increase the distance by setting `margin-left:15px` for the second panel doesn't give the desired result: the second panel is simply shifted 15 pixels right and goes out of the window. How can I control the distance between the panels?

Comment: Did you try binding those columns(the ones which needed to be of same size) into a single div and then applying same class with width=50%

Comment: @AravindAnil Like this: `<div style="width:50%"><td>...</td><td>...</td></div>`? It doesn't change the appearance. Or may be I just misunderstand you? Could you give an example?

Comment: Before I jump into misdirecting you, is it necessary for you to retain the html structure as 3 <tr> ?

Comment: @AravindAnil Actually I have 2 `<tr>` and 3 `<td>` in the second `<tr>`. And not, I need only the appearance, other methods also fit.

Comment: FYI: `valign` is a deprecated HTML5 attribute and should be replaced with CSS rules.

Comment: @KostasX Thank you, replaced with `vertical-align: top;` for `td`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully solved the problem using CSS `grid` as it was suggested by [Aravind Anil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6512929/aravind-anil) in the comments. Here is the solution:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: #CCCCCC;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        .item-header {
            grid-area: header;
            justify-self: center;
            padding: 1rem;
           
        }

        .item-sidebar {
            grid-area: sidebar;
            padding: 1rem;
        }

        .item-main-1 {
            grid-area: main-block-1;
            background: white;
            padding: 1rem;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .item-main-2 {
            grid-area: main-block-2;
            background: white;
            padding: 1rem;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr;
            grid-template-areas:
                "header header header"
                "sidebar main-block-1 main-block-2";
            grid-column-gap: 15px;
            grid-row-gap: 15px;
            width:100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="item-header">
            Header
        </div>
        <div class="item-sidebar">
            buttons
        </div>
        <div class="item-main-1">
            first
        </div>
        <div class="item-main-2">
            second
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="mainTable">
    <col width="auto">
    <col width="auto">
    <tr height="50px" valign="top">
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td valign="top">
         <p style="width:200px">some objects of fixed width</p>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" height="100%">
          <div class="panelsMain" style="width:50%">sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</div>
          <div class="panelsMain" style="width:50%">fffffffff</div>
       </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Somewhat structure like this can achieve the result you asked for.  Also make sure to add sufficient margin-right to the middle div to get the intended look. Please correct me if I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thank you, after wrapping both panels with `<nobr></nobr>` the desired appearance is almost achieved. How it is best to control the distance between the panels in order to set it equal to `15px` (as `border-spacing:` in `table`)?

Comment: I believe you may have to go for some relative size for the first panel (instead of auto). The issue is other panels are not aware of this 'auto' set size. In order to get such a flexibility I highly recommend you to use grids/flexboxes which will take care of the entire available space effectively :) https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Thank you for directing me to `grid`, I was able to solve the problem using it. Please see my answer.